# Android app running on one device but not on another device

Tags: android

My android maps app is running on few devices like moto g4, moto g2, yu yunicorn .etc but not on the other devices like mi note 4g. I have checked the maps API and other things but the app crashes on the MI note

Comment: put your logcat error here

Comment: show Crash log please.

Comment: paste your logcat

Comment: have you tested it by yourself, is it a crash report from google play console or is it a user reclaim? There could be several reasons for this, if a crash report is available, you should post it with the relevant part of code.